# Using DataSource without app-server

Tags: java

My data access objects takes a DataSource as a parameter which works perfectly if they are deployed within an app server.

I'm wondering how I can assemble a data source from within a simple Java class. This might also be useful for unit testing?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing magic about a DataSource. It's [just an interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html). Spring has a [basic one for testing purposes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) if you're already using Spring. [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) is all about providing a [pooling DataSource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.4/index.html). Pretty much any other JDBC connection pooling library out there will also provide a DataSource implementation. Just instantiate it, set the properties, and run with it.